# How to fix: "Items from database are missing after deploying on Heroku"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-5

After deployment of the Web Application (online store) written in Ruby On Rails on Heroku the products from the database are not displayed. I deployed and I migrated the database using 'git push heroku master' and then 'heroku run rails db:migrate'. I'm using PostgreSQL and Paperclip gem for image upload.

I tried to upload a new products from deployed application and it works.

```
                <% @products.each do |product| %>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="cart h-100">
                            <% if product.image.present? %>
                                <%= link_to image_tag(product.image.url(:thumb)), product_path(product)%>
                            <% end %>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title"><%= product.name %></h4>
                                <h5><%= product.price %></h5>
                                <p class="card-text"><%= product.description %></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">
                                <% if current_user && current_user.admin? %>
                                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %>
                                    <%= link_to 'Delete', product_path(product), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                                <% elsif current_user && !current_user.admin %>
                                    <%= form_tag(line_items_path(product_id: product.id)) do %>
                                        <%= number_field_tag(:quantity, 1) %>
                                        <%= submit_tag('Add to shopping cart') %>
                                    <% end %>
                                <% elsif !user_signed_in? %>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
```

I expected the display of items from the database, but after migration, the products are still missing and i can only add them from deployed application.

Comment: "I expected the display of items from the database, but after migration, the products are still missing and i can only add them from deployed application." What migration? Where do you expect these products to appear from?

Comment: You're not expecting `products` from your local/development environment to show up in your Heroku/production environment, are you?

Comment: The issue nr. 1 is that i can't migrate/show up my products from local environnement. 
The issue nr. 2 is that once the `product` is added from deployed application, the text data appears only the image is not displayed. Would that mean I need another location to store my files? If yes, what would you recommend? 
Thank you for help!

Comment: I read this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#international-users-additional-configuration about image upload, but i had some problems with configuration and in the meantime I found another solution: Active Storage for Rails 5 - i'll try to implent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your databases are by default completely independent between your various Rails environments: anything you do on your local machine exists only your local machine, not on Heroku (and vice-versa). (After all, you wouldn't want your test products showing up in your live store.)

If you have specific database records that always need to be present — whether you're on your local development machine, or in your test environment, or in production on Heroku — that's why the [Active Record "seed" feature](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) exists.